PIM: Mandatory justification when approving requests
In PIM, whatever Activation & Assignment settings I put in the role, when approving the role, I will always have to enter justification.
Is the justification mandatory when approving a role? I couldn't find anything about that in Microsoft Learn.
If there's a way to change this to not require justification, let me know.
PIM approving justification

While you can create a PIM request without justification, depending on the decisions of admins setting up those PIM roles, it does not appear that a PIM request Approval (or Denial) can be done without the justification, or, at least, Microsoft's documentation does not indicate this is optional. From their documentation:

Approve requests
Note: Approvers are not able to approve their own role activation requests.
1. Find and select the request that you want to approve. An approve or deny page appears.
2. In the Justification box, enter the business justification.
3. Select Submit. You will receive an Azure notification of your approval.


https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/id-governance/privileged-identity-management/pim-approval-workflow#approve-requests
